# how can I use this statement for accounts in my organization without writing each account out individually?

Tags: amazon-web-services

Hi guys please how can I use this statement in this KMS KEY POLICY for accounts in my organization without writing each account out individually?I can not use PrincipalOrgID with the service.I need some help please

```
{
  "Sid": "Enable CloudTrail Encrypt Permissions",
  "Effect": "Allow",
  "Principal": {
  "Service": "cloudtrail.amazonaws.com"
},
 "Action": "kms:GenerateDataKey*",
"Resource": "*",
"Condition": {
"StringLike": {
  "kms:EncryptionContext:aws:cloudtrail:arn": [
    "arn:aws:cloudtrail:*:111111111111:trail/*",
    "arn:aws:cloudtrail:*:222222222222:trail/*"
  ]
}
```

}
}

Answer (score 0):

I feel you on this one . It's a major pain to efficiently whitelist your organization when the org ID  condition isn't available. Im afraid you'll have to whitelist all account ids as a list as you're doing here.

The dirty way around is is to wildcard the account id. It would theoretically enable all AWS accounts to use your kms key to encrypt their cloudtrail logs, but I still have to think of a use case where that is a major risk.
But from a compliance perspective this isn't really an option.

Fortunately when whitelisting, tools like the CDK or pulumi make it a bit easier to perform logic like loops and lookups when deploying your infrastructure. So if it's within your skillset, I'd recommend using these tools.